# How to change the keyboard input in vscode in chromebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-os, chromebook, keyboard-layout, keyboard-input

I am working on Chromebook today and I can't find how to change the keyboard language in vscode in Chromebook.

Changing keyboard input language in other apps works fine but not in vscode and obsidian.

I hope I can get through somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to change the keyboard layout or the keyboard language? You probably change settings in the Chromebook.

Comment: Does that mean the Chromebook's keyboard layout and that of vscode are different?
In particular?
For example, Chromebook is USA, vscode is Germany.

Comment: No, I meant it won't change the language in vscode on Chromebook! Changing the language works in other apps

Comment: How do you usually change the kyboard language in other apps?